# How to group by and loop through sub-group values in SSRS report builder

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using SSRS report builder with SharePoint lists. I've created a Matrix in report builder that groups **site evaluation status** by **organization**. I would like to be able to set the background color of the cell of holding the organization name, depending on the overall evaluation status of the sites that belong to the organization.

My site evaluation status values are "not started", "in progress", "complete". If any of the organization's sites have a status of "not started", then the background color of the organization's cell is red. As long as all of the organization's sites have a status of "in progress", then the organization's background cell is yellow. Finally as long as all of the organizations sites have a value of "complete", then the organizations background color is green.

Example in Excel
[image: Example using Excel]

I know how to change the background color of the cell using an expression to call code, but not sure how to pass the values I need or loop through those values. I think I have to write something in VB in the custom code section, but not sure how to loop in within a group with Report Builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this expression in the background color property of Organization:

```
=Switch(
Array.IndexOf(LookupSet(Fields!Organization.Value,Fields!Organization.Value,Fields!Status.Value,"DataSet2"),"Not Started")>-1,"Red",
Array.IndexOf(LookupSet(Fields!Organization.Value,Fields!Organization.Value,Fields!Status.Value,"DataSet2"),"In Progress")>-1,"Yellow",
Array.IndexOf(LookupSet(Fields!Organization.Value,Fields!Organization.Value,Fields!Status.Value,"DataSet2"),"Complete")>-1,"Green"
)
```

It produces this:

[image]

**UPDATE 1:**

The [Switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dft2z9yf(v=vs.90).aspx) function evaluates every case:

1. Status column contains `Not Started` values
2. Status column contains `In Progress` values.
3. Status column contains `Complete` values).

In order to check if there is a `Not Started` value in the Status column, I used [IndexOf()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) and [LookupSet()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240819.aspx) functions. LookupSet will give me an array containing every Organization status, so using IndexOf I search Not Started, In Progress or Complete values. In case a value is found it returns the index where it is stored in the array otherwise it returns -1.

**UPDATE 2:** Edition based on user comments.

First you have to understand how Switch function works in SSRS. In fact, it is really simple, every row is evaluated against every case expression of the Switch function. When a row match the condition, there is a `Not Started` value i.e. the next row is evaluated against every condition in the Switch function and so on.

> Note the cases are evaluated in the order they were written. So in our
>   scenario every row is evaluated firstly against the condition where it
>   contains `Not Started` values if the condition is `false`, it
>   continues to the next condition, if it is `false` it continues to the
>   next condition and so on, until a condition is true or all conditions
>   are evaluated.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Alejandro, thanks! That is a work of art and it works :) Now I need to figure out what all the different components do. The SSRS Report Builder documentation didn't help me much on this.

Comment: @M_66, I've updated my answer to add a brief explanation and references.

Comment: yes that helps. I still have one question that I can't figure out. I understand how the LookupSet() and the Array.IndexOf() methods work, but I don't quite understand what is happening when you loop through each set and some of the values in the set have a status Not Started and others have a status of In Progress. So, when it is looping through, how come it doesn't assign the Organization status color based on the last item in the list? How does it know to assign the proper status to the organization? Hope that question makes sense.

Comment: @M_66, Check my update 2. I am glad you want to know how it works. Generally OP's don't come back to SO after solving their problem based on the answers even if they don't understand how the answer solved the problems.